# Using H-lookups in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am searching through 1000's of lines of data and I'm looking for specific info in these cells and if it appears id like the end cell to have a tick in or turn red and ect. for easy distinguish.

So in short what I am looking for would be

```
All Selected cells    
if (all cell a-z Contain "Admin"){
    Tick cell AA
}
```

Comment: Use conditional formatting to highlight cells containing specific text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked out a solution to the range issue instead of highlighting all of the cells

```
=IF(ISERROR(HLOOKUP("admin",A5:G5,1)),"NOT FOUND","FOUND")
```

Hope this helps anyone else out there.

Comment: This would only work if any of `A5:G5` contain *only* `admin`. If only one cell contains (say) `The admin`, it won't be found. Of course, if this was your intention all along, then I guess it wasn't that clear from the question.

Answer (score 2):

You should check for `Admin` inside a concatenation of the cells `A1:Z1`. This concatenation is achieved via `A1&B1&C1&...&X1&Y1&Z1`. So, for example, in cell AA1, enter

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("Admin",A1&B1&C1&...&X1&Y1&Z1)),"not found","found")
```

where you replace `...` with the remaining cells in the range.

Comment: how would you apply  this over a range say a1:z1?

Comment: @BenWilson: The formula or the conditional formatting?

Comment: the range to search for admin so, admin could be located in any cell from a1 to z1 and if it appears in any of these cells then make cell AA say found

Comment: @BenWilson: I've updated my answer to accommodate for this. It wasn't clear to me from the original question.

Comment: It Works, surly there has to be an easier way though, but thanks this will save me some time

Comment: @BenWilson: Yes, you can use VBA to cycle through the ranges or write a macro (a so-called UDF/Use Defined Function) that you can use in a cell to cycle through the ranges (see, for example, [Concatenate Multiple Cells with Array Formula](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/365691-concatenate-multiple-cells-array-formula.html) for a function `joinall`). It all depends on what you're willing to use and what works for you.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is as follows. In the cell you want the indicator have the following code, and assuming that you are looking for the value a - replace "a" with the value you are looking for.

```
=COUNTIF(D8:I8,"a")
```

You can then use conditional formating that says if the cell is > 0 then turn it red, or have an adjacent field that has a conditional format to put in a traffic light, tick mark, whatever and hide the previous field.

Hope this helps